# The new leaves near the stem of my Dracaena are turning black

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis

Why are these turning black.. they were green when I got this plant a few weeks black. Also the tips of some of the leaves are turning brown..please help.. I am new to this.. I am watering after checking the soil is dry

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The brown tips indicate it is getting too dry between waterings. I have not seen black leaf stumps but I occasionally pull the brown stumps off , maybe they would turn black if left.

Answer (score 2):

The black leaves at the bottom are normal. They were once protective sheaths for new growth and are no longer needed. You can remove them.

Dracaena are one of the types of plants that are especially sensitive to the fluoride in tap water. That causes brown leaf tips. Watering the plant with distilled water will solve that problem.

Other things that cause brown leaf tips are improper watering and too low humidity.
You should allow the top 1-2 inches of soil to become dry to the touch between watering.

You can raise the humidity around the plant by grouping it with other plants (all plants give off moisture through respiration). Another way is to place a small dish filled with rocks and water near the plant. The evaporation of the water will raise the humidity around the plant.